# como fazer um carrinho de compras simples com react js

Tags: javascript, react

eu gostaria de saber como se faz uma simples adição de compra no react js mostrando a quantidade de items adicionado em uma div e o preço calculado sempre que adicionar um novo item, eu ja baixei outros projetos para tentar identificar como se faz, mas não era especificamente o que eu queria(ou eu não sabia ler o código com clareza), que é clicar na div com o preço, adicionar ao carrinho, mostrar a quantidade e custo total

abaixo tem o código que fiz no codepen, eu ja fiz outra pergunta postando o codepen e editaram removendo ele, então não sei se pode postar ou não, obrigado desde já

```js
this.state = {
produtos: [
   { titulo: 'ham1', preco: '5,00'},
   { titulo: 'ham2', preco: '7,50'},
   { titulo: 'ham3', preco: '6,50'},
   { titulo: 'ham4', preco: '7,50'}
   ],  
  conta: 0,
  carrinho: 0,
};


function Total(props) {
  return(
    <div className="person">
      <p className="espaco">items {this.state.carrinho}</p>
      <p className="espaco">$ {this.state.conta}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
function comprar() {
alert('ola')
}

function Conteudo(props) {
  return(
<div className="person">
  
<div className="espaco" onClick={this.comprar}>
  hamburguer: 5,00</div>
<div className="espaco" onClick={this.comprar}>
  hamburguer: 7,50</div>
<div className="espaco" onClick={this.comprar}>
  hamburguer: 6,50</div>
<div className="espaco" onClick={this.comprar}>
  hamburguer: 7,50</div>
 
    </div>
  )
}


var app = (
  <div>
  <Total />   
  <Conteudo />   

  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(app,
document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
.person {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #eee;
 box-shadow:  0 2px 2px #ccc;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 20px;
 }

.espaco {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.espaco:hover {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Olha só esse link: https://medium.com/@ayabellazreg/make-a-simple-shopping-cart-app-using-react-redux-1-3-fefde93e80c7